# Export $DISPLAY value in Shell script

Tags: bash, display, scripts

I am trying to Print the value of $DISPLAY under my Shell script.

I have Following shell script which Exports the DISPLAY:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DIPLAY=:10.0
```

Here, each time I need to change the Value manually to accomplish the task.

Can we make the DISPLAY value dynamic using command:

```
echo $DISPLAY  'Prints the current Display Value :10.0
```

I have tried with the below code but it won't assigns the DISPLAY value to the variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DIPLAY=echo $DISPLAY
```

Below is the complete Code:

```
#!/bin/sh 
export DISPLAY=:10.0 
export ANT_HOME=/home/abc/Desktop/Eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502 
cd /home/abc/Desktop/auto/Automation/xyz 
ant usage clean compile build run makexsltreports sendemail
```

I am running this shell script every hour using crontab job

Please suggest!!

Comment: You want to set DISPAY to your current display value?

Comment: Yes, but need to assign in a shell script.

Comment: Did you realize that you have a typo in your `sh` script? It's missing an **S**: `DISPLAY` vs. (your) `DIPLAY`. ;)

Comment: This solved for me, because I was look for a way to store DISPLAY value to a variable:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057343/how-do-i-automatically-set-the-display-variable-for-my-current-session

Answer (score 4):

`echo $DISPLAY` won't work. If it did, you wouldn't need to set or export `DISPLAY` in the first place. You'll need to find out what the appropriate value is using some other way.

If you want to find out what `DISPLAY` your user is currently running, try:

```
w -h $USER | awk '$2 ~ /:[0-9.]*/{print $2}'
```

Then you can do:

```
export DISPLAY=$(w -h $USER | awk '$2 ~ /:[0-9.]*/{print $2}')
```

- [`w`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/w.1) lists the currently logged-in users and where they are logged in from, with `DISPLAY` being used for users logged in by GUI.
- With `awk`, we match the second field, the location, to something that looks like a `DISPLAY` and print it out.

Comment: @muru When tried `w -h $USER | awk '$2 ~ /:[0-9.]*/{print $2}'` prints :0

Comment: @ChetanG that's the idea. The display for your logged in user is shown. If it is supposed to be something else, how is it derived?

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment as I don't have 50 points yet. Just want to comment on the answer by muru: awk needs to print the third column for the DISPLAY number (at least in 16.04), since the second column `"$2"` prints the tty number.

so instead of:

```
w -h $USER | awk '$2 ~ /:[0-9.]*/{print $2}'
```

it should be:

```
w -h $USER | awk '$3 ~ /:[0-9.]*/{print $3}'
```

I use:

```
DISPLAY_M=$(echo "export DISPLAY"$(w -h $USER | awk '$3 ~ /:[0-9.]*/{print $3}' | sed 's/\:/=\:/')
```

When called it prints the full `export DISPLAY=:0`. The sed part is to add the `=` to the echo.

Thanks muru.

Answer (score 1):

The command should be:

```
#!/bin/bash    
export DISPLAY=$(echo $DISPLAY)
```

Here you need to use the command substitution functionality i.e. `$(command)` of `bash`.

**EDIT:**

Now after seeing your full script i am getting the whole picture.

First create a file in your `home` directory for example `/home/abc/display_check` having the following line:

`echo $DISPLAY`

Now in your original script add a line `source /home/abc/display_check` i.e. your original script can take the following form:

```
#!/bin/bash 
export DISPLAY=$(source /home/abc/display_check)
export ANT_HOME=/home/abc/Desktop/Eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502 
cd /home/abc/Desktop/auto/Automation/xyz 
ant usage clean compile build run makexsltreports sendemail
```

Comment: I have tried with above code but still unable to make the output.

Comment: change the shell to `bash`. Check my edits.

Comment: Nope....`#!/bin/bash` will ensure that it is being interpreted by `bash`.

Comment: Not Working with the above change.

Comment: @ChetanG: can you show me an example of what you are doing..

Comment: Please add that to your [original question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/581922/edit) in exact form.

Comment: @heemayl FYI You can use the shortcut `[edit]` in your comments to link to the edit screen for the current question.